# Create a Linked Server in SSMS to a MySQL Database on a Remote Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssms, remote-server, linked-server

I am trying to create a linked server to a MySQL database but I keep getting the Error 7303: Data Source name not found and no default driver specified.

- The database is on a server that I have to remotely connect to using a login and password

  - I use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to the server
- I have created both 64 bit and 32 bit system DSN's that successfully connect when tested

Here are the strings I am using:

**- For 64 bit:**

> EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ECWIMA64'
>   ,@srvproduct=N'MySQL' ,@provider=N'MSDASQL' ,@datasrc=N'ECWIMA'
>   ,@provstr=N'Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI
>   Driver};DATABASE=mobiledoc;OPTION=134217728;PWD=password;UID=SQLUser;SERVER=ip
>   address;Port=port' EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname =
>   N'ECWIMA64', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser =
>   N'*\Administrator', @rmtpassword = N'password'

**- For 32 bit:**

> EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
>       @server = N'ECWIMA32'
>       ,@srvproduct=N'MySQL'
>       ,@provider=N'MSDASQL'
>       ,@datasrc=N'ECWIMA32'
>       ,@provstr=N'Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};DATABASE=mobiledoc;OPTION=134217728;PWD=password;UID=SQLUser;SERVER=ip
>   address;Port=port'
>       EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'ECWIMA32', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser =
>   N'*\Administrator', @rmtpassword = N'password'

Also, I'm not IT so please dumb it down for me.

Here is the next try:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
@server = N'ECWIMA64' 
,@srvproduct=N'MySQL'
,@provider=N'MSDASQL'
,@datasrc=N'ECWIMA'
,@catalog=N'mobiledoc'
,@provstr=N'Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};DATABASE=mobiledoc;OPTION=134217728;PWD=password;UID=SQLUser;SERVER=ipaddress;Port=4928;ODBC:DSN=ECWIMA'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'ECWIMA64', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser = N'*\Administrator', @rmtpassword = N'password'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the ODBC data source? You need to create the data source first and reference the data source name:

```
@provstr=N'ODBC:DSN=YourDataSourceName'
```

e.g.:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ECWIMA64' ,@srvproduct=N'MySQL' ,@provider=N'MSDASQL' ,@datasrc=N'ECWIMA' ,@provstr=N'ODBC:DSN=ECWIMA',@catalog=N'MySqlSchemaName'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'ECWIMA64', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser = N'MysqlAccount', @rmtpassword = N'password'
```

You need to give the mysql db name and the mysql account for the linked server

Comment: Yes:  @datasrc=N'ECWIMA'

Comment: Then you use the DSN directly. I updated the answer. You also need to specify the mysql schema/db name for the @calalog

Comment: Tried it and no luck